# Is it true that by changing my mac address it will keep me anonymous when using wifi?

Tags: linux

Ubuntu:
**Background**: (1) Let’s assume I am sitting at an indoor wifi hotspot cafe and my computer savvy enemy is sitting next to me. He wants to get remote access to my computer by dropping malware/ trojan onto it. (2) I’m using a paid vpn & free wifi.

After doing some research, I found out that 3 of the best things I can do to protect myself at a wifi hotspot is to (1) use a vpn (2) change the mac address on my computer (3) don’t use the hotspot, but bring my own (ie: verizon) monthly paid device which gives me internet access.

For this post, I'm only concerned about someone connecting remotely to my computer by dropping malware/ trojan on it at a wifi hotspot, and also, how much protection I will get mainly by changing my mac address on my laptop; let’s assume they do not already know what the real mac is.

From the research I’ve done, it seems that they first have to identify me on the network, but they won’t be able to if my mac address is changed to 00:11:22:33:44:55.

But I’m concerned that maybe they could just send malare to everyone in the store using that hotspot, even if they don’t see me on the network.

Also, that there may be some program or method to find me on the network even if I have hidden my real mac address, get malware on my computer, or, bypass the whole mac address method and go another route.

I know a vpn can help protect from a MITM attack, but I don’t see how it would help me protect against a trojan getting sent to my computer under these circumstances.

Comment: "He wants to get remote access to my computer by dropping malware/trojan onto it." … this simply isn't possible

Comment: @Fox Dropping a RAT (remote access trojan) on it. I would have to respectfully disagree.

Comment: Contrast https://security.stackexchange.com/q/172315/6216 and https://security.stackexchange.com/q/153594/6216 ; and notice that there's nothing specific to Unices or Linux in the question.

Comment: @JdeBP The computer's OS is ubuntu; I stated at the very beginning.

Comment: And none of the question is specific to it, as I said.  You could have prefixed a completely random name and made no difference to the question, as indeed _you did_ with [tag:macintosh].

Comment: You can't just "drop a RAT" on some arbitrary computer. The T stands for Trojan, as in, something the user was tricked into initiating. Without an actual attack like a MITM, that's not happening

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a cybersecurity question and should be posted on [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I also vote to move this question to SECURITY_SE. How do I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They can't just
"*For this post, I'm only concerned about someone connecting remotely to my computer by dropping malware/ trojan on it at a wifi hotspot, and also, how much protection I will get mainly by changing my mac address on my laptop; let’s assume they do not already know what the real mac is."*

If you are using a VPN they can't see your traffic.

They can't just send malware to everyone on the network, they possibly could use MIM attack to glean passwords. They could possibly scan the network for open ports on the PC's to see if there are exposed ports as well as figuring out the OS's. You need to keep learning my friend, if you keep you OS updated that is probably the number 1 thing you can do to protect yourself.

Comment: @sipysip The user still needs to initiate it....A remote access Trojan (RAT) is a malware program that includes a back door for administrative control over the target computer. RATs are usually downloaded invisibly with a user-requested program -- such as a game -- or sent as an email attachment. Once the host system is compromised, the intruder may use it to distribute RATs to other vulnerable computers and establish a botnet.

Comment: I know some ppl in law enforcement and they told me that if a suspect uses a certain hotspot often, they figure out what the range of ip addresses is for that place and then send RAT's to that ip address range until it lands on the suspect's computer; and that's how they initially get on their computer. But there needs to be an open port for the RAT to "report" back to the law enforcement. I don't know all the details of it.

Comment: I say wtih 99% certainty that getting the RAT on the computer for the purpose of admin control and remote access does not have to be user-initiated. They may be able to pinpoint my computer if they know I use linux and not many others are using linux there, but if I am using a vpn, I am guessing that this info would be hidden from them, and that mac spoofing would make it harder for them to find me, unless they are doing what law enforcement does.

Comment: Additionally, I've known ppl in the past who stated to me that they got on their ex-girlfriend's computer, but that they had to know her ip address, and then they sent a RAT there.

Comment: There's no way for that to happen unless a service is running and accepting connections. The police statement unless they are using known exploits is just false.

Comment: Mark: So maybe it is accepting connections. From a general standpoint, law enforcement gets on thousands of computers every year by using RATS and ppl's IP addresses. Most ppl, including me, don't know much about ports.

Comment: @sipysip I mean this with all due respect, but if you admittedly don't know much about ports (any by extension networking in general) then perhaps it's safe to assume these things you're so sure of are incorrect? The vast, vast majority of modern operating systems don't accept unsolicited connection requests. They have firewalls to prevent that from happening. Most likely the police are lying because making people fear what they don't know is an easy way to enforce compliance.